# Python's einsum equivalent in Mathematica?

Tags: tensors

Python's `numpy` has [einsum function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which allows to express wide range of combinations of ND-arrays multiplications, transposings, convolutions etc in one short expression. It is based on [Einstein's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) for tensor algebra.

It is much easier to unserstand `einsum` expression even for just matrix product.

In `Mathematica` I can't find any equivalent, and even simple linear matrix transform appeared in my code as follows:

```
modif = Sum[e[[chart, j]] * a[[j]], {j, 1, Dimensions[e][[2]]}];
```

A lot of indexings and complex `Sum` expression.

Is there still `einsum` equivalent in Mathematica?  If there isn't, how could I implement a similarly convenient notation myself, without sacrificing too much performance?

**UPDATE**

The benefits of `einsum` it has in my opinion are following:

1) You should not think about order of operands and should not transpose them to correct shape.

For example, suppose you want to multiply matrix $A$ of `(5,5)` by vector of $X$ which you would write in math as $AX$. But suppose your vector $X$ is transposed to row `(1, 5)` which made $AX$ illegal.

You can compute

$(X(A^T))^T$

which can be easily miskaten as

$(XA)^T$

if you forget one transpose and it will work.

With einsum you would write

$a_{ij} x_{kj}$

where repeating of $j$ automatically means [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction) and since it is in second position, it goes along row.

With `einsum` notaion you can even transpose result as you want:

```
np.einsum("ij,kj->ik", a, x)
```

will give column, while

```
np.einsum("ij,kj->ki", a, x)
```

will give row.

But you are not need to worry about it, because `einsum` can take any transpose.

2) You can easily deal with stacks of matrices and vectors and you should not think about how to extract them.

Suppose that now `a` is `10` matrices of compound shape of `(10,5,5)` and you want to multiple all of them by the same `x` and get `10` results stacked. Then I'd write

```
np.einsum("ijk,lk->ijl", a, x)
```

Or suppose `x` is also a stack of vectors and I want to multiply each matrix to corresponding `x`. The I would write

```
np.einsum("ijk,ilk->ijl", a, x)
```

Now the presense of `i` in output pattern also means no contraction.

3) `einsum` can be used to multiply more that `2` tensors in one expression.

You will NEVER use any other matrix operations, once you learn `einsum` and have efficient implementation of it!

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a single built-in that does what you want, but you can certainly make things easier by using `Listability` of `Times` to do `Total[e[[chart, All]] a]`, which gives the same result as your sum (assuming `a` has the appropriate dimensions).

Comment: Please include a number of example *in the question* that illustrate what einsum does.

Comment: Have also a look at `TensorProduct` and TensorContract`.

Comment: @Szabolcs it's very powerfull function, enumerating usage examples will overload the question. If one doesn't know what `einsum` does, he/she can't help then.

Comment: With that attitude, you just made me regret that upvote I gave you in advance.

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry for troubles :(

Comment: I think some of your recent questions sound a bit link complaining that Mathematica doesn't have certain unusual numpy features (whether or not you meant them that way).  But I also think that these questions could be made interesting and useful to many people.  `einsum` is something so specific that it is very unlikely that any other system would have it. The answer to your literal question is that no, Mathematica doesn't have einsum. But writing such an answer is not very useful to anyone.  That is why I edited your question and asked how to implement it.

Comment: As you said, einsum is a "huge" function that can do many things. Imitating it *exactly* is not very exciting.  But creating something comparable is.  To get people's attention, and to get them excited, I suggest you describe a few basic but interesting use cases in the question itself, or even maybe show how you imagine a similar Mathematica function could be used (usage example, not implementation). It is important to include this in the question because most people won't click through to your link, and won't even realize that the question is interesting.  Presentation really does matter :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs I disagree. `einsum` is more general, then other operations and more clear to read; it would be better to remove all that Dot, Cross, Outer and so on, which are really specific, and retain only `einsum`

Comment: After reading your comment, I am not really sure *what* you are disagreeing with. But it certainly makes it sound like this post isn't really a question, just a (non-constructive) criticism of Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs it was a question, does `Mathematica` have `einsum` equivalent. "Equivalence` questions are very popular in SO and are often asked by persons, who are switching from language to language, like me. It is strange that you percepted this as aggression against `Mathematica`. At least because `Mathematica` is not a religion, but just a tool. 

Anyway I wrote some examples of `einsum` useges, which I was able to take from the top of my head.

Comment: @Dims completely unrelated to Mathematica, but your note that you'll never use another matrix operation sounded some alarm bells in my mind. For efficiency, `einsum` is often not the best. `numpy` has a crazy efficient `dot` function (it's all BLAS at the end there and well parallelized). Lots of stuff built off of this `dot` are similarly fast.  This often also crushes `einsum` which due to its generality can not be as well parallelized. Mathematica has a similarly efficient `Dot` and thus there are many, many cases where that takes precedence over `einsum`'s convenience.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can implement most of your `einsum` functionality using [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract)/[`TensorTranspose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorTranspose). Here is an implementation, but note that it will not work with indices that are repeated but not contracted, and index specifications that don't match the corresponding array's depth:

```
einsum[in_List->out_, arrays__] := Module[{res = isum[in->out, {arrays}]},
    res /; res=!=$Failed
]

isum[in_List -> out_, arrays_List] := Catch@Module[
    {indices, contracted, uncontracted, contractions, transpose},

    If[Length[in] != Length[arrays],
        Message[einsum::length, Length[in], Length[arrays]];
        Throw[$Failed]
    ];

    MapThread[
        If[IntegerQ@TensorRank[#1] && Length[#1] != TensorRank[#2],
            Message[einsum::shape, #1, #2];
            Throw[$Failed]
        ]&,
        {in, arrays}
    ];

    indices = Tally[Flatten[in, 1]];

    If[DeleteCases[indices, {_, 1|2}] =!= {},
        Message[einsum::repeat, Cases[indices, {x_, Except[1|2]}:>x]];
        Throw[$Failed]
    ];

    uncontracted = Cases[indices, {x_, 1} :> x];

    If[Sort[uncontracted] =!= Sort[out],
        Message[einsum::output, uncontracted, out];
        Throw[$Failed]
    ];

    contracted = Cases[indices, {x_, 2} :> x];
    contractions = Flatten[Position[Flatten[in, 1], #]]& /@ contracted;
    transpose = FindPermutation[uncontracted, out];
    Activate @ TensorTranspose[
        TensorContract[
            Inactive[TensorProduct] @@ arrays,
            contractions
        ],
        transpose
    ]
]

einsum::length = "Number of index specifications (`1`) does not match the number of arrays (`2`)";
einsum::shape = "Index specification `1` does not match the array depth of `2`";
einsum::repeat = "Index specifications `1` are repeated more than twice";
einsum::output = "The uncontracted indices don't match the desired output";
```

Here is your first example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
x = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];

einsum[{{1,2}, {3,2}} -> {1,3}, a, x]
```

> {{1.18725, 1.14471, 1.23396}, {0.231893, 0.203386, 0.416294}, {0.725267, 
>     0.673465, 0.890237}}

Compare this with:

```
a . Transpose[x]
```

> {{1.18725, 1.14471, 1.23396}, {0.231893, 0.203386, 0.416294}, {0.725267, 
>     0.673465, 0.890237}}

Here is your second example:

```
einsum[{{1,2}, {3,2}} -> {3,1}, a, x]
x . Transpose[a]
```

> {{1.18725, 0.231893, 0.725267}, {1.14471, 0.203386, 0.673465}, {1.23396, 
>     0.416294, 0.890237}}
>
> {{1.18725, 0.231893, 0.725267}, {1.14471, 0.203386, 0.673465}, {1.23396, 
>     0.416294, 0.890237}}

Your third example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = RandomReal[1, {3,2,2}];
x = RandomReal[1, {2,2}];

einsum[{{1,2,3}, {4,3}} -> {1,2,4}, a, x]
a . Transpose[x]
```

> {{{0.373209, 0.890669}, {0.380332, 0.926471}}, {{0.11833, 
>      0.290096}, {0.286499, 0.720608}}, {{0.340815, 0.964971}, {0.274859, 
>      0.824754}}}
>
> {{{0.373209, 0.890669}, {0.380332, 0.926471}}, {{0.11833, 
>      0.290096}, {0.286499, 0.720608}}, {{0.340815, 0.964971}, {0.274859, 
>      0.824754}}}

As I said earlier, repeated indices that aren't contracted are not supported by my implementation, so your 4th example won't work. Finally, if you give `einsum` symbolic arrays, it will still work:

```
Clear[a, x]
$Assumptions = a ∈ Arrays[{10,5,5}] && x ∈ Arrays[{5,5}];

einsum[{{1,2,3}, {4,3}} -> {1,2,4}, a, x]
```

> TensorContract[a \[TensorProduct] x, {{3, 5}}]

Comment: Hm, I need "ij,kl->ikjl" pattern and it doesn't seem to work: x = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}; einsum[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} -> {1, 3, 2, 4}, x, x] (* TensorTranspose::ttrank: Permutation {1,3,2,4} moves slots beyond tensor rank 2.*)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It works for me in M12. Perhaps there's a version dependency?

Comment: Aha, seems to work fine in Mathematica Online, I may have redefined one too many system symbols

Answer (score 2):

There is now a Resource Function that implements Einsum. https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/EinsteinSummation/

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work with contracting more than two indices at once.