# How to implement Einstein summation convention with differential operators

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, tensors

**Statement of this problem:**

In the textbook, the following differential equilibrium equations can be expressed by tensors:

[image]

Using Einstein's summation convention, the formula in the figure above can be abbreviated as follows:

[image]

In addition, the strain coordination equations in the figure below can be abbreviated as:

[image]

[image]
It can be abbreviated as
[image]

I would like to know how to implement the above summation convention with the help of MMA's tensor operator.

My problem is slightly different from [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158179/pythons-einsum-equivalent-in-mathematica) because I have involved derivation operations and I need to use notation like $div(σ)+F=0$ to memorize differential equilibrium equations to reduce the burden of memorizing deformable compatibility equations.

---

**Objectives to be addressed of this question：**

I want to find a universal tensor operation function to express the equations expressed by various tensors in elasticity as shown in the figure below (thank you very much for xzczd's answer, which has made a good demonstration meeting my requirements).

[image]

If I could, I would like to find a way to express the deformation compatibility equation expressed by strain or stress in a similar way as $div(σ)+F=0$ represents the equilibrium differential equation, so as to reduce the burden of memory.

---

**That's the main purpose of this question. I hope I can solve this problem with your help.**

> **What needs further explanation in the comments:**
>
> The tensor operation I mentioned mainly refers to the tensor with derivative in the textbook. For example, `kl` after the comma in the lower corner of $e_{ij,kl}$ represents the second derivative of $e_{ij}$.  This is different from the usual tensor description.
>
> Part of my question can also be expressed as "can I have a function that convert $σji,j+Fi=0$ to ".
>
> [The textbook](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000006630019&d=D21C2B211974FF3ABF0F9AA338EA6FB0&fenlei=13020703) I used didn't specify the specific meaning of the first two `ee`, but I saw the relevant answers, I think it should mean `LeviCivitaTensor`.

Comment: Which "tensor operator" do you mean. As is, this question is very vague. You migh want to have a look at `Div`; it works also on matrices. Actually, a basis-free notation for the above would be $\operatorname{div}(\sigma) + F = 0$, wo why struggling with indices?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you very much for your comment. In addition, I would like to know if there is a similar simple notation for the strain coordination equations in the figure above.

Comment: @henrik I guess OP's question can be rephrased as "Can I have a function that convert $\sigma{ji,j}+F_i=0$ to …". (Still, OP's clarification is necessary of course. ) "Why struggling with indices" Einstein summation convention appear in text books about fluid dynamics, solid mechanics, etc. quite a bit, being able to handle this with _Mathematica_ is useful, I think.

Comment: Yeah, true: One has to be able to read the literature. But the second set of equations posted by OP just underlines my point: Can you tell what they mean? At least, I cannot.

Comment: @henrik The second set is indeed confusing. If I guess it right, there exist two kinds of $e$ here. The first two $e$ i.e. $e$ in $e_{mik}e_{nlj}$ actually denote `LeviCivitaTensor`, and the last two $e$ denote strain. (Once again, we still need OP's clarification, of course. )

Comment: @Edmund Sadly it doesn't, it focus on Einstein summation convention used in list manipulation. Actually we already have a few questions related to Einstein summation convention, but none of them seems to be a duplicate of OP's question, AFAIK.

Comment: ……同学你编辑问题的时候能不能走点心。你这越编辑越乱了。

Comment: @xzczd 英语不熟练，下次提问多花点精力进行排版。

Comment: 1. ……贴图都是小问题，虽然用$\LaTeX$会更好。2. 你应该对别人在评论里要求进一步解释（clarify）的问题有所回应，比如我在我头两条评论里猜的内容，到底对不对；问题也应该做相应的修改。3. “If I could, I would like to find a way to express the deformation compatibility equation expressed by strain or stress in a similar way as div(σ)+F=0 represents the equilibrium differential equation, so as to reduce the burden of memory.” 这段已经完全是另一个问题了，在评论里问问也罢，但你不该把它塞到问题里去。

Comment: @xzczd 我其实也是想回复他们要求进一步解释的内容的，可是这块的专业术语我不知道用英语怎么说（比如我描述的"tensor operator" 我也不知道它具体的英文学术名称），我就暂时没回复，下次我提问和评论时，我多花点时间和精力查找相关术语并有条理的阐述排版相关问题。

Comment: ……为什么非得等到下次？因为你问题写的不清楚你的问题已经快被关闭了看见了没有。

Comment: 我也看到问题即将被关闭，但我确实想不出该怎么回答这些问题，毕竟我不能为了回复评论而使用不正确的陈述，我已经在问题中简单的回复了评论中关心的内容，但肯定不能表述正确，等我再仔细想一想，我再更改相关问题陈述。感谢你指出的问题，不过我可能需要很长时间才能准确回复评论中关切的内容。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aha, simpler than I thought. Assuming all I guessed in the comments is correct:

```
BeginPackage["einstein`"]

allowtensor;
$tensordimension = 3;

Begin["`private`"]

expand[func_, {}] := # &
expand[func_, var_] := 
 Function[s, func[s, ##] &[Sequence @@ ({#, $tensordimension} & /@ var)], HoldAll]

tensor[index_List] := 
 Function[{expr}, 
  With[{count = Count[expr // Unevaluated, #, Infinity, Heads -> True] & /@ index}, 
   expand[Table, Pick[index, OddQ[#] && # > 0 & /@ count]]@
    expand[Sum, Pick[index, EvenQ[#] && # > 0 & /@ count]]@expr], HoldAll]

flat[expr_List] := Flatten@expr
flat[expr_] := expr

SetAttributes[allowtensor, HoldFirst]
allowtensor[a_ + b_, index_List] := allowtensor[a, index] + allowtensor[b, index]
allowtensor[c_ a_, index_List] /; FreeQ[Unevaluated@c, Alternatives @@ index] := 
 c allowtensor[a, index]
allowtensor[a_ == b_, index_List] := 
 flat@allowtensor[a, index] == flat@allowtensor[b, index] // Thread
allowtensor[expr_, index_List] := tensor[index][expr]

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

The following is not necessary, but will make the output pretty:

```
rule[var_] := var[i__] :> Subscript[var, Sequence @@ x /@ {i}]

drule = Derivative[id__][f_][args__] :> 
   TraditionalForm[
    HoldForm@D[f, ##] &[
     Sequence @@ (DeleteCases[
         Transpose[{{args}, {id}}], {_, 0}] /. {x_, 1} :> x)]];
```

Then let's check. Some preparation:

```
inde = {x, y, z};

Clear@x; x[i_] := inde[[i]];
```

Oh, I've used `x` both for function definition and independent variable, which isn't a good practice, but this is just a toy example and we know what we're doing, so let it be.

Now check the first example:

```
allowtensor[D[σ[i, j][x, y, z], x[j]] + F[i] == 0, {i, j}] /. 
  rule /@ {σ, F} /. drule
```

[image]

The second:

```
ϵ = LeviCivitaTensor[3];

allowtensor[ϵ[[m, i, k]] ϵ[[n, l, j]] D[e[i, j][x, y, z], x[k], x[l]] == 0,
            {i, j, k, l, m, n}] /. 
    e[i_, j_] /; i > j -> e[j, i] /. rule[e] /. 
  drule // DeleteDuplicates
```

[image]

Notice the output is eliminated to 6 equations because of the symmetry, which should have been clarified in the body of question.

Comment: Your answer is very good. I want to know if you can use differential operators and matrix operations to memorize deformable compatible equations(Similar to using $div(σ)+F=0$ to memorize differential equilibrium equation).

Comment: Why is the result of the following code `True`?
`allowtensor[(D[e[i, j][x, y, z], x[k], x[l]] + 
        D[e[k, l][x, y, z], x[i], x[j]] - 
        D[e[i, k][x, y, z], x[j], x[l]] - 
        D[e[j, l][x, y, z], x[i], x[k]]) == 0, {i, j, k, l, m, n}] /. 
    e[i_, j_] /; i > j -> e[j, i] /. rule[e] /. 
  drule // DeleteDuplicates`.

 According to the definition of the textbook, it should be the same as the result of $emik \;enlj\;eij, kl = 0$.

Comment: @pl 1. `curl = Curl[#, {x, y, z}] &; 
Flatten[curl /@ 
      Transpose[curl /@ Table[e[i, j][x, y, z], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]]] /. 
    e[i_, j_] /; i > j -> e[j, i] /. rule[e] /. 
  drule // DeleteDuplicates` 2. There's a bug in the original implementation, now it's fixed. Thx for testing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: I'd offer extra brownie points if you can generate those to be inactive operators for FEM in NDSolve ;-)

Comment: @user21 Oh that's much harder. Let me think about it…

Comment: @xzczd, this was half meant as a joke - but if you can figure this out, that would be *very* useful. But, please do not waste your time on it.

Answer (score 9):

Let me try to partially answer. Partially for the following reason: I know how to implement index vector and tensor notations and how to work with them. I also wanted to implement the Einstein convention and failed. However, even without it one can successfully use the index notations.

Let us first introduce the Kronecker, `\[Delta]` and Levi-Civita, `ee` tensors:

```
Subscript[δ, i_, j_] := KroneckerDelta[i, j];
Subscript[ee, i_, j_, k_] := Signature[{i, j, k}];
```

Let us try them. This looks as

[image]

on your screen. I mean that on the screen it looks as we traditionally used to denote vectors and tensors in the index notations, but in the StackExchange is is clumsy. Therefore, in the following I include the screenshots.

```
Subscript[ee, 1, 2, 3]
Subscript[ee, 1, 1, 3]

(* 1

0 *)
```

This is the contraction of the Levi-Civita with the Kronecker tensor

[image]

```
    Sum[Subscript[ee, i, j, k]*Subscript[δ, i, k], {i, 1, 3}, {k, 
       1, 3}] /. j -> 3
(* 0 *)
```

This is the example of a vector product:

[image]

```
Subscript[s, i_] := 
  Sum[Subscript[ee, i, j, k] Subscript[a, j] Subscript[b, k], {j, 1, 
    3}, {k, 1, 3}];
Subscript[s, 1]

-Subscript[a, 3] Subscript[b, 2] + Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[b, 3]
```

Here is an example of an electrodynamics calculation of the magnetic field [image] as a part of a Fresnel problem  within this technique

[image]

This is a simple example from the elasticity theory (since you seem to be interested precisely in this area):

[image]

```
Subscript[ϵ, 1, 1] = 
  1/Ε*(Subscript[σ, 1, 
     1] - ν*(Subscript[σ, 2, 2] + Subscript[σ, 3, 
        3]));
Subscript[ϵ, 2, 2] = 
  1/Ε*(Subscript[σ, 2, 
     2] - ν*(Subscript[σ, 1, 1] + Subscript[σ, 3, 
        3]));
Subscript[ϵ, 3, 3] = 
  1/Ε*(Subscript[σ, 3, 
     3] - ν*(Subscript[σ, 1, 1] + Subscript[σ, 2, 
        2]));
expr = (Sum[Subscript[ϵ, i, i], {i, 1, 3}]) /. 
   Subscript[σ, 3, 
    3] -> ν*(Subscript[σ, 1, 1] + Subscript[σ, 2, 
       2]) // Factor

(* -(((1 + ν) (-1 + 2 ν) (Subscript[σ, 1, 1] + 
    Subscript[σ, 2, 2]))/Ε)  *)
```

I have more examples from elasticity theory including operating with derivatives and Green functions. However, I feel that this answer is already too long.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The compatibility equations (from George Herrmann's Elasticity Notes at Stanford in 1978). [image] I think he took this course from Ray Mindlin (look him up----excellent)

This shows how to express them in "dyadic" form and Cartesian tensor form. Perhaps this, along with Alexei's nice answer will help you. I might adopt his nice notation for Kronecker and Alternating symbols.

Note as pointed out in the comments, both the alternating (Levi-Civita) and strain occur in these equations and they both have a symbol that resembles e. So make your handwriting better than mine was then.