# Klein-Gordon Equation: how can I write the summation?

Tags: differential-equations, summation, physics, tensors

I would like to write a program that gives me the Klein Gordon Equations given a metric. I will explain.

My code is in the following:

**I) Standard Quantities**

I have no doubt here the first part is [given by Hartle's](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Egravitybook/mathematica.html).

```
Clear[coord, metric, inversemetric, affine, riemann, ricci, 
      scalar, einstein, t, x, y, z]

n = 4;
coord = {t, r, θ, ϕ};

metric = {{-(1 - ((2*m)/(r))), 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, (1)/(1 - ((2*m)/(r))), 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, r^2, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, r^2*(Sin[θ]*Sin[θ])}};

inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];
Det[metric]
```

**II) MY TRY**

I wrote the components by hand:

```
KG00 = FullSimplify[((1)/(Sqrt[-Det[metric]]))*
    D[(Sqrt[-Det[metric]])*(inversemetric[[1, 1]])*
      D[Ξ[t, r, θ, ϕ], t], t]];

KG11 =  FullSimplify[((1)/(Sqrt[-Det[metric]]))*
    D[(Sqrt[-Det[metric]])*(inversemetric[[2, 2]])*
      D[Ξ[t, r, θ, ϕ], r], r]];

KG22 = FullSimplify[((1)/(Sqrt[-Det[metric]]))*
    D[(Sqrt[-Det[metric]])*(inversemetric[[3, 3]])*
      D[Ξ[t, r, θ, ϕ], θ], θ]];

KG33 =  FullSimplify[((1)/(Sqrt[-Det[metric]]))*
    D[(Sqrt[-Det[metric]])*(inversemetric[[4, 4]])*
      D[Ξ[t, r, θ, ϕ], ϕ], ϕ]];

KG00 + KG11 + KG22 + KG33
```

**III) What I would Like**

I would like to use summation convention on the code of section **II)**, since the Klein-Gordon equations are given by:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\sum_{\mu=1}^{4}\sum_{\nu=1}^{4}\partial_{\mu}\Bigg(\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu} \Psi(r,\theta,\phi,t) \Bigg) \tag{1}$$

**IV) Hartle's code on summation convention**

Actually, Hartle's $[1]$ gives an way to work with tensor indexes, for instance the Christoffel Symbols are given by:

$$ \Gamma^{s}_{jk}=\sum_{s=1}^{4}\frac{1}{2}g^{is}\Bigg(g_{sj,k} + g_{sk,j} - g_{jk,s} \Bigg) \tag{2}$$

and the code using summation is:

```
affine := 
  affine = Simplify[
    Table[(1/2)*
      Sum[
         inversemetric[[i, s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
          D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - 
           D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), 
         {s, 1, n}
      ],
      {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}
    ] ];

listaffine := 
  Table[
    If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 0],
       {ToString[Γ[i - 1, j - 1, k - 1]], 
       affine[[i, j, k]]}
    ],
    {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}
  ];

TableForm[
  Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], 
  TableSpacing -> {2, 2}
]
```

Comment: You mean something like this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216806/1871

Comment: @xzczd yes, einstein summation convention.

Answer (score 6):

We can use this code for Klein-Gordon:

```
Clear[coord, metric, inversemetric, affine, riemann, ricci, scalar, \
einstein, t, r, θ, ϕ]

n = 4;
coord = {t, r, θ, ϕ};

g = {{-(1 - ((2*m)/(r))), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/(1 - ((2*m)/(r))), 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, r^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, r^2*(Sin[θ]*Sin[θ])}};

g1 = Simplify[Inverse[g]];
dg = Det[g];
KG = 1/Sqrt[-dg] Sum[
   D[Sqrt[-dg] g1[[i, j]] D[psi[t, r, θ, ϕ], coord[[j]]], 
    coord[[i]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]
```

Now we can compare `KG` with spherical Laplacian

```
KG /. m -> 0 // FullSimplify

Laplacian[psi[t, r, θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ}, 
  "Spherical"] // FullSimplify
```

And we see that two expression differ on second derivative $\partial_t \partial_t \psi$ as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can try my [`allowtensor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216806/1871). Since it's a 4D problem, you need to set the value of global variable `$tensordimension` to `4`:

```
dmetric = Det[metric];
ref = KG00 + KG11 + KG22 + KG33;
$tensordimension = 4;
mykg = allowtensor[
   1/Sqrt[-dmetric] D[Sqrt[-dmetric] inversemetric[[i, j]] D[Ξ[t, r, θ, ϕ], 
                      coord[[j]]], coord[[i]]], {i, j}];

mykg == ref // Simplify
(* True *)
```

Definitions of `metric` etc. are the same as yours.