# Derivative of real antisymmetric matrix in mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, tensors

Is it possible to find the derivative of components of a real antisymmetric matrix using index notation? Eg: I have a very large real antisymmetric matrix. Then from Matrix Cookbook, we know the formula that: $$\frac{dx_{k\ell}}{dx_{\beta\alpha}}=\delta_{k\beta}\delta_{l\alpha}-\delta_{k\alpha}\delta_{l\beta}$$ This formula is a general one and can be applied to any indices. So is there a way to define this in Mathematica for any general indices? That means even if I use, $$\frac{dx_{ab}}{dx_{cd}}$$,it should return the answer without any other definition. Is this possible? Please help as I am new to Mathematica. Some other equations that can be obtained from the above relation of differentiation real antisymmetric matrices are given as: $$\frac{d}{dx_{\beta\alpha}}\left(x_{\upsilon l}x_{k\mu}\right)=\left(\delta_{\upsilon\beta}\delta_{l\alpha}-\delta_{\upsilon\alpha}\delta_{l\beta}\right)x_{k\mu}+x_{\upsilon l}\left(\delta_{k\beta}\delta_{\mu\alpha}-\delta_{k\alpha}\delta_{\mu\beta}\right)$$ $$\frac{d}{dx_{\beta\alpha}}\left(x_{k\alpha}x_{\beta l}\right)=-2\left(D-1\right)x_{lk}=2\left(D-1\right)x_{kl}$$ $$\frac{d}{dx_{\beta\alpha}}x_{j\alpha}=\delta_{j\beta}\delta_{\alpha\alpha}-\delta_{j\alpha}\delta_{\alpha\beta}=\left(D-1\right)\delta_{j\beta}$$ But my issue is that this is not the only indices I need to use. I need to find out the same with other indices. So is there is a way that Mathematica can find it automatically. Also in the below expression, I have implemented the product rule. $$\frac{d}{dx_{\beta\alpha}}\left(x_{\upsilon l}x_{k\mu}\right)=\left(\delta_{\upsilon\beta}\delta_{l\alpha}-\delta_{\upsilon\alpha}\delta_{l\beta}\right)x_{k\mu}+x_{\upsilon l}\left(\delta_{k\beta}\delta_{\mu\alpha}-\delta_{k\alpha}\delta_{\mu\beta}\right)$$ So if these things can be calculated by Mathematica, then I can check my calculations. D is the dimension of the real antisymmetric matrices. $$ \sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}=-\sum_{ijkl}f_{jikl} $$ The above tensor f is defined in such a way that we can exchange it's indices such a way that one exchange of neighboring indices results in a negative sign. Two nearby exchanges result in no change in sign. $$ \sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{k\alpha}^{-}\frac{dx_{ij}^{+}}{dx_{\beta\alpha}}x_{\beta\ell}^{+} $$ $$= \sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{k\alpha}^{-}\left(\delta_{i\beta}\delta_{j\alpha}-\delta_{i\alpha}\delta_{j\beta}\right)x_{\beta\ell}^{+}$$ $$=\sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl} x_{k\alpha}^{-}x_{\beta\ell}^{+}\delta_{i\beta}\delta_{j\alpha}-\sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{k\alpha}^{-}x_{\beta\ell}^{+}\delta_{i\alpha}\delta_{j\beta}$$ $$=\sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl} x_{kj}^{-}x_{i\ell}^{+}-\sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{ki}^{-}x_{j\ell}^{+}$$ $$= \sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{kj}^{-}x_{i\ell}^{+}-\sum_{jikl}f_{jikl}x_{kj}^{-}x_{i\ell}^{+}$$ $$= \sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{kj}^{-}x_{i\ell}^{+}+\sum_{ijkl}f_{jikl}x_{kj}^{-}x_{i\ell}^{+}$$ $$= 2\sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{kj}^{-}x_{i\ell}^{+} $$ Utilizing the antisymmetric property of x matrices we can rewrite the above expression as: $$ \sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{k\alpha}^{-}\frac{dx_{ij}^{+}}{dx_{\beta\alpha}}x_{\beta\ell}^{+}=-2\sum_{ijkl}f_{ijkl}x_{jk}^{+}x_{i\ell}^{+} $$ We have $$ x_{kj}^{-}=x_{kj}-i\delta_{kj}=-x_{jk}-i\delta_{kj}=-x_{jk}^{+} $$
When I try to evaluate the following code:

```
myD[x[v, l] - x[β, α], x[p, u]]
```

with  the following before,

```
myD[a_ - b_, c_] := myD[a, c] - myD[b, c]
myD[a_ + b_, c_] := myD[a, c] + myD[b, c]
```

It's returning zero.

[image: Click]

Comment: Do you mean something like this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216806/1871

Comment: Hi @xzczd, I have read that. Great work and thanks for your comment. But I am new to Mathematica and I am not sure how to convert it to my case. What I need is to calculate mathematical calculations involving Einstein summation symbolically in Mathematica.

Comment: Er… Do you mean things like $\delta_{k\beta}$ should not evaluate to a explicit list `Table[KroneckerDelta[x, y], {x, 3}, {y, 3}]`?

Comment: Those deltas are normal Kronecker deltas. But in my case as you expressed we can't express it as a matrix. I am doing all calculations using Einstein notations. Also mine is not a 3 X 3 matrix. It is a very large matrix, maybe 500 X 500 ! So only possibility is using index

Comment: The question is still a bit unclear to me. Seems that you're working with explicit lists, then I think my `allowtensor` can be used. Just adjust `$tensordimension` to `$tensordimension = 500`. If you still have difficulty in coding, please show us a more specific example.

Comment: Thanks for the message. But the issue with me is that I don't need to use a matrix dimension in my case. I need to check some symbolic differentiations. I can edit the question again to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi xzczd, Please have a look at the modified question.

Comment: OK, so you need implicit tensor, and that's somewhat beyond my reach. Let's wait for someone more knowledgable. You might have some luck with the xAct package:  http://www.xact.es/ (I myself never tried it so can't say much. )

Comment: Thanks xzczd for useful comments and your time. I can have a look at xact.es.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a second thought I notice it's not that hard to implement:

```
ClearAll[myD, δ]

myD[x_[k_, l_], x_[β_, α_]] := δ[k, β] δ[l, α] - δ[k, α] δ[l, β]
myD[a_ b_, c_] := a myD[b, c] + b myD[a, c]

SetAttributes[δ, Orderless]
δ /: δ[a_, b_] h_[former___, b_, latter___] := h[former, a, latter]
δ[a_, a_] = \[FormalCapitalD];
```

The following rule isn't necessary but will make the output pretty:

```
Format[δ[a_, b_]] := Subscript[δ, a, b]
Format[x[a_, b_]] := Subscript[x, a, b]
```

Test:

```
myD[x[a, b], x[c, d]]
```

[image]

```
myD[x[v, l] x[k, μ], x[β, α]]
```

[image]

```
myD[x[k, α] x[β, l], x[β, α]] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
myD[x[j, α], x[β, α]]
```

[image]

```
myD[x[v, l] x[k, μ], x[β, α]]
```

[image]

The property of antisymmetric matrix isn't used in the calculation above so I don't implement it, but it should be easy to add if needed.

---

As to the new example, just define the following rule for `f`:

```
Clear[f]
f[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} f @@ Sort@{arg}
```

Then the index of `f` will be sorted in lexicographical order (dictionary order).

Again, the following is not necessary, but will make the output pretty:

```
Format[f[arg__]] := Subscript[f, arg]
```

Test:

```
f[j, i, k, l]
```

[image]

```
f[i, j, k, l] x[k, α] myD[x[i, j], x[β, α]] x[β, l] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
% /. {α -> j, β -> i}
```

[image]

Still, the antisymmetric property of `x` doesn't play a role here so I don't implement it, but you can add the property in the same manner as defining `f`.

Comment: You are an amazingly talented guy. This is exactly what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is it possible to add the property of the real antisymmetric matrices? That would be really helpful.

Comment: @Jasmine Can you show me an example in which the antisymmetric property plays a role?

Comment: Hi xzczd, I have edited the question again. Can you please see the details

Comment: @Jasmine Check my update.

Comment: No words. Simply amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: One quick question,     myD[a_ - b_, c] := myD[a, c] - myD[b, c]   When I try to implement the subtraction rule of derivatives just like the product rule you have defined, I am getting zero as the answer!

Comment: @Jasmine It should be `myD[a_ - b_, c_]`. BTW, as to implementation of linearty, you may want to read this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871

Comment: But it's not working. I have edited my original. Can you please see the last part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110797/discussion-between-jasmine-and-xzczd).