Can Mathematica differentiate summation notation with respect to an indexed variable?
My question is whether Mathematica can represent an expression such as:
$$y_i = \sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} x_j$$
symbolically as a sum over indefinite bounds (unknown $N$), and differentiate it with respect to an indexed variable such as $a_{ik}$. The answer in this case should be $\partial y_i / \partial a_{ik} = x_k$.
For a more involved example, if we have
$$f_k = x_k \sum_i \sum_j g(a_{ij}, x_j)$$
then
$$\partial f_k / \partial x_n = \delta_{nk} \sum_i \sum_j g(a_{ij}, x_j) + x_k \sum_i \sum_j D_2 g(a_{ij}, x_j) \delta_{nj}$$
$$=\delta_{nk} \sum_i \sum_j g(a_{ij}, x_j) +  x_k \sum_i D_2 g(a_{in}, x_n)$$
where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta and $D_2 g$ is the derivative of $g$ with respect to its second parameter.
Can Mathematica do both of these examples as stated?

With advice from a user on wolfram community, I tried:
Assuming[
 1 <= k <= z && k ∈ Integers
&& 1 <= n <= z && n ∈ Integers,
 ff = D[x[k] * Sum[Sum[g[a[i, j],x[j]], {j, 1, z}], {i, 1, z}], x[n]]
 ]

But this gives the wrong answer: Sum[Derivative[0, 1][g][a[i, n], x[n]], {i, 1, z}]*x[k]. It omits the other term in the answer.
Another user from Wolfram Community suggested trying
Assuming[
 1 <= k <= z && k ∈ Integers
&& 1 <= n <= z && n ∈ Integers,
 ff = D[If[n == k, x[n],x[k]]  * Sum[Sum[g[a[i, j],x[j]], {j, 1, z}], {i, 1, z}], x[n]]
 ]

which gives the result
If[k == n, 1, 0]*Sum[Sum[g[a[i, j], x[j]], {j, 1, z}], {i, 1, z}] + 
  If[k == n, x[n], x[k]]*Sum[Derivative[0, 1][g][a[i, n], x[n]], {i, 1, z}] 

This is technically correct but there are two problems. First, it doesn't convert the first If[] expression to a KroneckerDelta, and it doesn't eliminate the second If[] expression. It doesn't seem to be able to simplify If[] expressions much at all; in other testing I find it will leave If[expr, 0, 0] in that form without simplifying to 0. The second problem is that I need to add those If[] expressions for every variable, and if I have multiple "free" indices (in more complex examples than shown here) that's a lot of cases to handle, requiring me to test for every variable whether or not each of its indices is equal to any of the other indices in the expression. The expression gets so complicated that I'd be better off doing it by hand from the start than manually rewriting and simplifying the Mathematica output.

Hello, welcome to MMA.SE. Then, the new-in-14.1 ArraySymbol, etc. are related, they're not strong enough at the moment, though. But it's not too hard to code our own, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226082/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226431/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/245308/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/245585/1871 You'll find more by checking posts under tag [tag:tensors].

People here generally like users to post code as copyable Mathematica code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site, helpful

Similar question on WCommunity: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3315569

@MichaelE2 OK, I added some more code and discussion.

Generally, If[] is a programming construct and Piecewise[] is a functional construct. With version enhancements over the years, If[] is sometimes converted to or treated like Piecewise[], but maybe not perfectly. I don't know anything built-in that converts expression to KroneckerDelta[]. PiecewiseExpand will do the opposite.

Try PiecewiseExpand[] on your If[] result. I have to run to a meeting, but it seemed to work, I think.

OK, though I've done this many times, given that coding this in Mathematica requires one to have a good enough understanding for the core language, let me do a favor:
Clear[myD, mySum]

myD[a_ b_, c_] := a myD[b, c] + b myD[a, c]
(* Add the rule for addition just in case: *)
myD[a_ + b_, c_] := myD[a, c] + myD[b, c]

myD[mySum[a_, b__], x_] := mySum[myD[a, x], b]

myD[(h_ /; Context[h] =!= "System`")[a__], x_] := 
 With[{l = Length@{a}}, 
  Total@MapThread[
    Derivative[Sequence @@ #][h][a] myD[#2, x] &, {IdentityMatrix@
      l, {a}}]]

myD[Subscript[a_, i___, j1_, k___], Subscript[a_, i___, j2_, k___]] :=
  KroneckerDelta[j1, j2]

myD[Subscript[a_, __], Subscript[b_, __]] := 0

mySum[KroneckerDelta@OrderlessPatternSequence[i_, j_] expr_, jL___, 
  j_, jR___] := mySum[expr /. j -> i, jL, jR]

mySum[a_] := a

MakeBoxes[mySum[a__], fmt_] ^:= 
 With[{arg = MakeBoxes[#, fmt] & /@ {a}}, 
  With[{funcbody = 
     MakeBoxes[Sum[a], fmt] /. 
      Thread[arg -> (Slot /@ Range@Length@{a})]}, 
   TemplateBox[arg, "mySum", DisplayFunction -> (funcbody &)]]]

Usage:
myD[mySum[Subscript[a, i, j] Subscript[x, j], j], Subscript[a, i, k]]


myD[Subscript[x, k] mySum[g[Subscript[a, i, j], 
                            Subscript[x, j]], i, j], Subscript[x, n]]


You can press Ctrl+Shift+t to transform the output to TraditionalForm, and Ctrl+Shift+n to transform the output to StandardForm.

OK, you seem to know what you're doing so I'll take your word that this is necessary. So I'll start with your code and just implement my own symbolic transformation rules for everything in my expressions you didn't already handle. Seems simple enough at least. Thank you!

@causative Feel free to continue to ask if you have difficulty in implementing new rules :) .

It occurs to me that another thing I want to do is set these expressions equal to 0 and solve for xk (separating it out from each sum by writing aik xk + ∑j≠k aij xj, then simplifying and isolating all the xk on the left hand side). That seems more complicated, do you have an example of how I might do something like that?

@causative I can't recall any existing post at the moment. It's not hard to code for this specific task, though: eqn = 0 == mySum[Subscript[a, i, j] Subscript[x, j], j] /.    mySum[expr_, j_] /; ! FreeQ[expr, Subscript[x, _]] :> mySum[expr, j != k] + (expr /. j -> k) then Solve[eqn, Subscript[x, k]]. We may need a bit more effort to make this operation more general.

@causative Here's a more general rule: myD[Subscript[x, k]     mySum[g[Subscript[a, i, j], Subscript[x, j]], i, j], Subscript[x,    n]] /. mySum[expr_, jL___, j_, jR___] /; !      FreeQ[expr, Subscript[x, _]] :>    mySum[expr, jL, j != k, jR] + (expr /. j -> k)

By design of Mathematica the D operator differentiates an expression wrt to symbols or expressions, that are identifiable as patterns. So you get
 Subscript[f,j] = Sum[Subscript[a,j,k] x^k,{k,1,n}  
        (*never use N* or other capital letter symbols*)
 D[Subscript[f,j],Subscript[a,p,q]]
 0

for any values of p,q except j,k, simply because the pattern is not present in f. But if you differentiate wrt to the actual pattern and setting assumptions accordingly
Assuming[j \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
     D[Subscript[f, j], Subscript[a, j, k]]] 

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 x^k & j\geq 1\land j-n\leq 0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$
In effect this is use of Einstein's ingenious notation shortcut: working with the symbolic kernels of multilinear constructs like sums, integrals of tensor products and linear forms.

But I do want to differentiate with respect to variables with indices not present in the expression, as in the examples. Is there a workaround?
