# Operator products summing

Tags: pattern-matching, tensors

Is there a way to perform the below summation in Mathematica?

$$\frac{\left(\hat{X}_{ij}+\mathbb i\delta_{ij}\right)}{\mathbb{i}}\frac{\left(\hat{X}_{kl}+\mathbb i\delta_{kl}\right)}{\mathbb{i}}$$

I am finding the issue because order matters here. X is operator. So it's order is important. g and X are  antisymmetric tensors. The answer to the above equation I am expecting is:

$$-\text{test}=\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\frac{\left(\hat{X}_{ij}+\mathbb i\delta_{ij}\right)}{\mathbb i}\frac{\left(\hat{X}_{kl}+\mathbb i\delta_{kl}\right)}{\mathbb i}   
=-\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\left(\hat{X}_{ij}+\mathbb i\delta_{ij}\right)\left(\hat{X}_{kl}+\mathbb i\delta_{kl}\right)    
=-\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\left(\hat{X}_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}+\mathbb i\hat{X}_{ij}\delta_{kl}+\mathbb i\delta_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}+\mathbb i\mathbb i\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}\right)    
=-\left(\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\hat{X}_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}+\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\mathbb i\hat{X}_{ij}\delta_{kl}+\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\mathbb i\delta_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}+\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\mathbb i\mathbb i\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}\right)  
=-\left(\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\hat{X}_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}+\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijll}\mathbb i\hat{X}_{ij}+\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijll}\mathbb i\hat{X}_{kl}+\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijll}\mathbb i\mathbb i\delta_{ij}\right)   $$

Since $g$ is an antisymmetric tensor, if any of the two indices are same then it will be zero. Thus, $$g_{ijll}=0$$

Thus we get the answer:
$$test=-\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\hat{X}_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}$$

Can I implement this using the following code:

```
SumHeld /: MakeBoxes[SumHeld[expr_, ranges__], form_] := 
 MakeBoxes[Sum[expr, ranges], form]

SumHeld /: 
  SyntaxInformation[
   SumHeld] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Table", {2, Infinity}}};
SumHeld /: c_?NumericQ SumHeld[rest_, range__] := 
 SumHeld[c rest, range]
IndexUnify[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, __] ..]] := 
 Plus @@ With[{targetIndices = List @@ #[[-1, 2 ;;, 1]], 
      sourceIndicesList = List @@@ #[[;; , 2 ;;, 1]]}, 
     Function[{sum, sourceIndices}, 
       sum /. Thread[
         sourceIndices -> 
          Take[targetIndices, Length@sourceIndices]]] @@@ 
      Transpose@{#, sourceIndicesList}] &@
  SortBy[Flatten /@ {sums}, Length]

SumTogether[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, sameRanges__] ..]] := 
 SumHeld[Plus @@ {sums}[[;; , 1]], sameRanges]
SumTogether[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, __] ..]] /; 
  UnsameQ @@ {sums}[[;; , 2 ;;]] := 
 Plus @@ SumTogether@*Plus @@@ GatherBy[{sums}, Rest]

SumHeld[expr_, {lst_List, 
   dim_}] := (term |-> 
    SumHeld[term, 
     Sequence @@ 
      Table[If[Count[term, patt, ∞] == 2, {patt, dim}, 
        Nothing], {patt, lst}]]) /@ expr
```

How to modify the above code to incorporate to handle operators?

Comment: Is $i$ imaginary unit? Are you sure the result given in $\LaTeX$ is correct?

Comment: @xzczd I have edited the question. There is a negative sign missing. Also i is imaginary unit.

Comment: Then I suggest making the imaginary $ \mathrm{i} $ upright, not to be confused with the index $ i $.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Alternatively, one may consider `\mathbf{i}`.

Comment: “I am finding the issue because order matters here. X is operator. So it's order is important. ” The statement is a bit confusing to me. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @xzczd This is because X_ij X_kl is not equal to X_kl X_ij

Comment: Then why does $-\sum_{i,j,k,l}\left(g_{ijkl}\hat{X}_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}+ig_{ijkl}\hat{X}_{ij}\delta_{kl}+ig_{ijkl}\delta_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}-g_{ijkl}\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}\right)=-\sum_{i,j,k,l}g_{ijkl}\hat{X}_{ij}\hat{X}_{kl}$? Is $\delta$ `KroneckerDelta`?

Comment: @xzczd I didn't understand what you meant?

Comment: I mean, knowing "g and X are antisymmetric tensors" doesn't seem to be enough to deduce the last summation, please clarify.

Comment: @xzczd Editted. I have elaborated

Comment: …Then, isn't this question essentially a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226190/1871 ?

Comment: @xzczd No. this is because in that problem, they were just matrix coefficients. But here they are operators, that means order matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SumHeld`, `IndexUnify` and `SumTogether` are almost irrelevant to this task, please avoid utilizing others' code blindly. Then, though not a duplicate, this question is strongly related to your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226190/1871). We just need to modify the rule there a little to make it handle non-commutative multiply.

We first define functions for expansion of non-commutative multiply. The first 3 definitions are taken from document of `NonCommutativeMultiply`:

```
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, c___]] := 
 Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]]
ExpandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a]
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
 Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &]

ExpandNCM[c_ (h : NonCommutativeMultiply)@a__] := c ExpandNCM[h@a] // Expand
```

Then, modify a bit the definitions of Kronecker delta in my previous answer to make it handle non-commutative multiply:

```
Clear[δ];
SetAttributes[δ, Orderless]
δ /: δ[a_, b_] h_[former___, b_, latter___] := h[former, a, latter]

δ /: (expr : Except[__δ]) ** δ[a_, b_] := δ[a, b] expr
δ /: δ[a_, b_] ** (expr : Except[__δ]) := δ[a, b] expr
```

Finally, take the definition of antisymmetric tensor from my previous answer and add one more definition so that $g_{ijll}=0$:

```
g[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} g @@ Sort@{arg}
      
g[___, a_, a_, ___] := 0
```

Now the desired output is obtained:

```
g[i, j, k, l] ((X[i, j] + I δ[i, j])/I) ** ((X[k, l] + I δ[k, l])/I) // ExpandNCM
(* -g[i, j, k, l] X[i, j] ** X[k, l] *)
```