# What is a good way to describe all kinds of basic equations in elasticity by tensor

Tags: tensors, mechanism

I see [here](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/34095023) that we can use tensors to represent the fundamental equations in elasticity.

[image]

But I don't know how to use the tensor operation in MMA to reproduce these equations. If you can, please provide some useful related resources, please.

I hope these tensors can be involved in operations, not just signs.

Comment: (-1) Why do you ask essentially the same question again?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216794/1871

Comment: @xzczd This is only a part of the problem (deformation compatibility condition and stress balance equation), while [this post](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/34095023) contains more basic equations (boundary equation expressed by displacement, etc.). For example: $\sigma_{ij} = G （u_{i，j}+u_{j，i}） + \lambda \varepsilon_{kk}\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: `allowtensor` is a general-purposed function for Cartesian tensor. Please put a bit effort to understand the answers you've obtained, rather than post questions blindly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Einstein summation convention with differential operators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216794/how-to-implement-einstein-summation-convention-with-differential-operators)

Comment: @xzczd Can you help me to see how to solve [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229599/want-help-with-proving-a-calculus-theorem)? I need a general and deep-seated method to solve it.