# Tensor transformation

Tags: tensors, coordinate-transformation

Consider the following tensor in coordinate basis
$T=T^{\mu}_{\nu\lambda} \partial_{\mu}\otimes dx^\nu \otimes  dx^\lambda$

in two dimensions with coordinates $x^1 = x$ and $x^2 = y$. We take $T^{\mu}_{\nu\lambda}$ to have the following
components:

$$
T^1_{11} = x^2;
T^1_{12} = xy;
T^1_{21} = 0;
T^1_{22} = y;
T^2_{11} = 0;
T^2_{12} = x^2y^3;
T^2_{21} = 0;
T^2_{22} = x
$$

By using the same coordinate transformation as in the lectures
$x' = 2x/y;\quad y' = y/2; $
compute $T^{\mu}_{\nu\lambda}$ in two ways: first by transforming the basis $\partial_{\mu}\otimes dx^\nu \otimes  dx^\lambda$ and then by using
the explicit transformation for components of a tensor. Show that the two calculations agree.

Using:

$T^{\mu'}_{\nu'\lambda'} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu'}}{\partial x^\mu}  \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}  \frac{\partial x^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\lambda'}} T^{\mu}_{\nu\lambda}$

$\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^{1'}} = y'\qquad \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x^{1'}} = -2y'/x' \qquad
\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^{2'}} = x'\qquad \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x^{2'}} = 2$

I know how to solve exercise (similar to the solved problem in: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712019.pdf on page 45,46), but am primarily interested in implementation of the problem in Matematica so as to check results.
Could anyone lend me some advice?

Comment: Could you please also post the desired results?

Comment: I was about to ask almost this exact question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The formula

$$T^{\mu'}_{\nu'\lambda'} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu'}}{\partial x^\mu}  \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}  \frac{\partial x^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\lambda'}} T^{\mu}_{\nu\lambda}$$

can be implemented in *Mathematica* in a straightforward manner:

```
tensorrule = 
 List @@ Unevaluated@(Subscript[T, 11]^1 == x^2; Subscript[T, 12]^1 == x*y; 
      Subscript[T, 21]^1 == 0; Subscript[T, 22]^1 == y; 
      Subscript[T, 11]^2 == 0; Subscript[T, 12]^2 == x^2*y^3; Subscript[T, 21]^2 == 0; 
      Subscript[T, 22]^2 == x) /. 
   Subscript[T, j_]^i_. :> {i, Sequence @@ IntegerDigits[j]} /. Equal -> Rule

T = tensorrule // SparseArray // Normal
    
eq = {x2 == 2 x/y, y2 == y/2};
xrule = Solve[eq, {x, y}][[1]]

xlst = {x, y};
x2exprlst = Last /@ eq;

xexprlst = xlst /. xrule;    
x2lst = {x2, y2};
    
Table[Sum[D[x2exprlst[[μ2]], xlst[[μ]]] D[xexprlst[[ν]], x2lst[[ν2]]] 
          D[xexprlst[[λ]], x2lst[[λ2]]] T[[μ, ν, λ]], 
      {μ, 2}, {ν, 2}, {λ, 2}], {μ2, 2}, {ν2, 2}, {λ2, 2}] /. xrule // Simplify
(*
{{{x2^2 y2^3, x2 y2^2 (4 + x2^2 (1 - 8 y2^3))}, 
  {x2^3 y2^2, 8 + x2^2 (-2 + 4 y2) + x2^4 (y2 - 8 y2^4)}}, 
  {{0, 8 x2^2 y2^6}, {0, 2 x2 y2 + 8 x2^3 y2^5}}}
 *)
```

My [`allowtensor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216806/1871) can also be used:

```
$tensordimension = 2;
allowtensor[
   D[x2exprlst[[μ2]], xlst[[μ]]] D[xexprlst[[ν]], x2lst[[ν2]]] 
   D[xexprlst[[λ]], x2lst[[λ2]]] T[[μ, ν, λ]], {μ, ν, λ, μ2, ν2, λ2}] /. xrule//Simplify
```

Compute by transforming the base is a bit advanced, but not too hard:

```
$PrePrint = # /. {(h : Dt)@a_ :> Row@{d, a}, partial@a_ :> Subscript["∂", a]} /. 
                 {x2 -> Subscript[x, 2], y2 -> Subscript[y, 2]} &;

dlst = Dt@xexprlst

partiallst = {partial@x2, partial@y2}.D[x2exprlst, {{x, y}}] /. xrule

Sum[T[[i, j, k]] partiallst[[i]]\[TensorProduct]dlst[[j]]\[TensorProduct]dlst[[k]] // 
    TensorExpand[#, Assumptions -> {x2, y2} ∈ Reals] &, 
 {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}] /. xrule // Collect[#, _TensorProduct, Simplify] &
```

$$x_2^2 y_2^3 \partial_{x_2}\otimes d {x_2}\otimes d {x_2} + 
 x_2 y_2^2 (4 + x_2^2 (1 - 8 y_2^3)) \partial_{x_2}\otimes d {x_2}\otimes d {
y_2} + \\x_2^3 y_2^2 \partial_{x_2}\otimes d {y_2}\otimes d {x_2} + (8 + 
x_2^2 (-2 + 4 y_2) + x_2^4 (y_2 - 8 y_2^4)) \partial_{x_2}\otimes d {
y_2}\otimes d {y_2} + \\
 8 x_2^2 y_2^6 \partial_{y_2}\otimes d {x_2}\otimes d {y_2} + (2 x_2 y_2 + 
8 x_2^3 y_2^5) \partial_{y_2}\otimes d {y_2}\otimes d {y_2}$$

Comment: That should be a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, manipulation of matrices is of convenience, so here I provide my version of codes.

First come the Jacobian matrices

```
rule = Solve[{ξ == 2 x/y, ψ == y/2}, {x, y}][[1]]

(jco = D[{ξ ψ, 2 ψ}, {{ξ, ψ}}] // SparseArray) // MatrixForm
(jcontra = D[{2 x/y, y/2}, {{x, y}}] /. rule // SparseArray) // MatrixForm
```

Then is the tensor $ T^\mu_{\nu\lambda} $

```
tenT = SparseArray[
    {{1, 1, 1} -> x^2, {1, 1, 2} -> x y,
     {1, 2, 2} -> y, {2, 1, 2} -> x^2 y^3, 
     {2, 2, 2} -> x
    } /. rule, 
   {2, 2, 2}
]
```

Finally with the [`TensorProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html)-[`TensorContract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract.html) combo, one gets the result

```
TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[jcontra, jco, jco, tenT],
    {{2, 7}, {3, 8}, {5, 9}}
] // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

Note that in the last step, effort should be put in to decide which pairs of indices needing contracting. And if the manipulated objects are sparse arrays, it will be efficient.

---

In the same spirit, Eq. (2.25) in your posted arXiv article is easily reproduced by the below codes

```
rule0 = Solve[{ξ == x^(1/3), ψ == Exp[x + y]}, {x, y}][[1]]
tenS = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> x, {2, 2} -> 1} /. rule0, 2];
(jco0 = D[{ξ^3, Log[ψ] - ξ^3}, {{ξ, ψ}}] // SparseArray) // MatrixForm
TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[jco0, jco0, tenS], 
    {{1, 5}, {3, 6}}
] // FullSimplify // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3):

Let' s call the original and the new base :

```
oldbase = {e1, e2}; (*Cartesian base*)
newbase = {b1, b2};(*new base, cov- and convariant will be clear from the context.*)
```

and call the  old Cartesian coordinates {x, y} and the new ones : {u, v}. Then  define rules to change from new to old coordinates and vise versa :

```
xy2uv = {2 x/y, y/2};
uv2xy = {u v, 2 v};
n2oc = Thread[{u, v} -> xy2uv]
o2nc = Thread[{x, y} -> uv2xy]
```

Then we get the Jacobian d (x, y)/d (u, v)  and its inverse:

```
ja = D[xy2uv, {{x, y}}]
invja = Inverse[ja]
```

This gives the components of the new covariant base vectors in columns relative to the old base. The new base is therefore :

```
covincartbase = ja
oldbase.covincartbase
```

The component of the contravariant  base in rows are obtained by:

```
conincartbase = invja
oldbase.conincartbase
```

We now have cov/contravariant bases relative to the Cartesian base. To get the inverse, the Cartesian base relative to  the new  covariant base in columns we use the inverse Jacobian.

```
cartincovbase = invja
cartinconbase = ja
```

Or as an alternative we could have used d (u, v)/d (x, y) and d(x,y)/d(u,v).
For convenience we can define rules for change of one base into the other.

```
cart2covbase = Thread[{e1, e2} -> {b1, b2}.cartincovbase];
cov2cartbase = Thread[{b1, b2} -> {e1, e2}.covincartbase];
cart2conbase = Thread[{e1, e2} -> {b1, b2}.cartinconbase];
con2cartbase = Thread[{b1, b2} -> {e1, e2}.conincartbase];
```

With these preliminaries we can now look at T .
To keep track of co/contravariant components I use the `TensorProduct` symbol .
T in Cartesian coordinates and T and with base vectors :

```
Tcartcoord = {{{x^2, x y}, {0, y}}, {{0, x^2 y^3}, {0, x}}}; Tcart = 
 Sum [Tcartcoord[[i, j, 
    k]] oldbase[[i]]\[TensorProduct]oldbase[[j]]\[TensorProduct]oldbase[[
     k]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}]
```

To get the components in the base: bi TensorProduct bj TensorProduct bk (where bi is contravariant, bj and bk the covariant part) :

```
t = Sum [Tcartcoord[[i, j, 
     k]] (oldbase[[i]] /. cart2conbase)\[TensorProduct](oldbase[[j]] /. 
       cart2covbase)\[TensorProduct](oldbase[[k]] /. cart2covbase), {i, 
    2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}];
t = TensorExpand [t, 
     Assumptions -> {{x, y, u, v} ∈ 
        Reals}] /. (b1 y)\[TensorProduct](b1 y) -> 
     y^2  b1 \[TensorProduct]b1 // Simplify;
comp1 = Total@Cases[t // Expand, x2_ # :> x2] & /@ 
  Flatten@Table[
    newbase[[i]]\[TensorProduct]newbase[[j]]\[TensorProduct]newbase[[k]], {i, 
     2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}]
```

There seems to be a bug with `TensorExpand`, the  term (b1 y) is not distributed over `Times`. We need to fix this by hand using `ReplaceAll`.

On the other hand, we can use the formula for transformation of tensor components. To transform from coordinates {x,y} to {u,v} we use: for the covariant components the Jacobian: d(x,y)/d(u,v) = ja  and for the covariant component the Jacobian  d(u,v)/d(x,y) = Invers[ja]= invja. The {u,v} components of T are then:

```
Tuvcoord[i1_, j1_, k1_] := 
 Sum[Tcartcoord[[i, j, k]] ja[[i1, i]]  invja[[j1, j]] invja[[k1, k]], {i, 
   2} , {j, 2} , {k, 2} ]
comp2 = Flatten[Table[Tuvcoord[i, j, k], {i, 2} , {j, 2} , {k, 2} ], 2] // 
  Simplify
```

Comparing the coefficients of the base tensors `bi\[TensorProduct]bj\[TensorProduct]bk`, you can convince yourself that both are the same:

```
comp1 == comp2 // Simplify
```

For conve3nience, everything together :

```
oldbase = {e1, e2}; (*Cartesian base*)
newbase = {b1, b2};(*new base*)
xy2uv = {2 x/y, y/2};
uv2xy = {u v, 2 v};
n2oc = Thread[{u, v} -> xy2uv];
ja = D[xy2uv, {{x, y}}];
invja = Inverse[ja];
covincartbase = ja;
oldbase.covincartbase;
conincartbase = invja;
oldbase.conincartbase;
cartincovbase = invja;
cartinconbase = ja;
cart2covbase = Thread[{e1, e2} -> {b1, b2}.cartincovbase];
cov2cartbase = Thread[{b1, b2} -> {e1, e2}.covincartbase];
cart2conbase = Thread[{e1, e2} -> {b1, b2}.cartinconbase];
 con2cartbase = Thread[{b1, b2} -> {e1, e2}.conincartbase];
Tcartcoord = {{{x^2, x y}, {0, y}}, {{0, x^2 y^3}, {0, x}}}; Tcart = 
 Sum [Tcartcoord[[i, j, 
     k]] oldbase[[i]]\[TensorProduct]oldbase[[j]]\[TensorProduct]oldbase[[k]],\
 {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}];
t = Sum [Tcartcoord[[i, j, 
      k]] (oldbase[[i]] /. cart2conbase)\[TensorProduct](oldbase[[j]] /. 
       cart2covbase)\[TensorProduct](oldbase[[k]] /. cart2covbase), {i, 
    2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}];
t = TensorExpand [t, 
     Assumptions -> {{x, y, u, v} ∈ 
        Reals}] /. (b1 y)\[TensorProduct](b1 y) -> 
     y^2  b1 \[TensorProduct]b1 // Simplify;
comp1 = Total@Cases[t // Expand, x2_ # :> x2] & /@ 
  Flatten@Table[
    newbase[[i]]\[TensorProduct]newbase[[j]]\[TensorProduct]newbase[[k]], {i, 
     2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}]
Tuvcoord[i1_, j1_, k1_] := 
 Sum[Tcartcoord[[i, j, k]] ja[[i1, i]]  invja[[j1, j]] invja[[k1, k]], {i, 
   2} , {j, 2} , {k, 2} ]

comp2 = Flatten[Table[Tuvcoord[i, j, k], {i, 2} , {j, 2} , {k, 2} ], 2] // 
  Simplify
comp1 == comp2 // Simplify
```

Comment: "There seems to be a bug with "TensorExpand", the term (b1 y) is not distributed over Times." More of a flaw in my view. The only example in the document is about assuming a variable to be an implicit vector…

Comment: Even if one makes the assumption that y is a e.g. real (.a scalar), it is still buggy.