# Implementing einsum in Mathematica

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, tensors

I've been using Carl Woll's [einsum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158179/pythons-einsum-equivalent-in-mathematica/158248#158248) function, but it's missing the ability to handle repeated indices.

For instance `np.einsum('i,i->i',w, w)` will perform a Hadamard product, so it makes sense for Mathematica's einsum to do the same for `einsum[{{1}, {1}} -> {1}, a, a]`.

Another example, the following einsum in Python produces outer product of diagonal of A with $a\odot b$

```
np.einsum('ii,j,j->ij', A, b, c)
```

In Mathematica syntax this could look like this:

`einsum[{{1,1}, {2}, {2} -> {1,2}, A, b, c]`

Jacob Biamonte [visualizes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.10049.pdf) this kind of structure using "COPY-tensor", but it's really just an edge with more than 2 endpoints - a hyper-edge, so it would be useful to have it supported

[image]

Comment: +1 would be nice to have this. I've made a version of EinsteinSummation that can do this [EinsteinSummation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/nikm/DeployedResources/Function/EinsteinSummation/). It replaces TensorContract with SymbolicTensors`ArrayContract, but it no longer works with the Inactive tensor product, so it doesn't compute optimal contraction order anymore.